# How to handle LogOut scenario in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am having Facebook login for my app, and also log out scenario in a setting form of my app. When i click on logout button, i am doing following steps and there are working fine.
1) Clearing the active session 
2) Closing Active session
3) Deleting the user token stored in NSuserdefault.

Now i have to launch Facebook login form again, after log out. this is working fine. 
Coming to problem now, before launching facebook login form, do i need to remove all the view controllers that i visited previously ?  i am not using navigation controller in my app, and all presenting and dismissing the view controllers are handled manually. while going from one view controller to other i am dismissing few view controller if i don't need them, few i am not dismissing as i need them when i go back to previous view controller. when user logs out, i will launch Facebook login form. but what about view controller that is still in memory? do i need to take care of this scenario as well? if i had to handle it on my own, then how to handle it?

i am launching Facebook login view controller from log out button as below.

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex==0)
{
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    [FBSession.activeSession close];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"UserId"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
   UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    FbLoginViewController *frm_athenticate = (FbLoginViewController *) [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"autenticate"];
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];


  MyAppDelegate * appsDelegate =(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  [appsDelegate.window setRootViewController:nil];
   [appsDelegate.window setRootViewController:frm_athenticate];      
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do logout scenario you probably move to the login page. All inapp controllers (except login page) should be deallocated to prevent memory leaks at this point. You can check it by adding `dealloc` method to all controllers and NSLog it when you do logout. and if some of them are still alive then you have to deallocate directly.

Comment: Hey Kabarga.. Thanks for reply. but how to get list of all view controllers that are alive in heap,and how to dealloc each one?

Comment: You can not get a list. (you can use Xcode Instruments to find leaks also) but incode you can just add dealloc method and add NSLog to it and see the logs in the process of the app and when logout. Then you can find the controllers that inited but not deallocated. concerning how to dealloc: you are using your way to create/dismiss viewcontrollers without navigation, so it depends on your code...